# Resize url image to equal parts

Tags: html, css

I need help with an html / css
in my application to upload the photo in the profile, the user needs to pass the url of the image, I save this url in the database and put this url in my HTML `$ {user.fotoProfile}`

however, when the image comes with equal proportions, eg. `150x150`, `650x650`, `960x960` whatever. the setup works and fills my field without distortion.

but when the image does not have equal proportions, the image field is distorted.

Can someone help me?

HTML

```
                     <div class="user-img">
                        <a href='profile'><img src="<c:url value="${user.fotoProfile}" />" alt="user-img" class="img-circle img-thumbnail img-responsive"></a>
                        <div class="user-status offline"><i class="zmdi zmdi-dot-circle"></i></div>
                    </div>
```

CSS

```
  .user-box .user-img {  position: relative;  height: 88px; width: 88px; margin: 0px auto; }

#wrapper.enlarged .user-box .user-img {  height: 48px;  width: 48px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put image as background-image and set it to fill your div, that way you get cutoff where dimension does not fit:

```css
div {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/200') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100%;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```